# NO <DUTY, RUN, PERIOD, POLARITY> in bone_capemgr.9(ocp.2/pwm_test_P8_13.#)FILE Beaglebone Black

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, linux-kernel, beaglebone

I just a fresher did the servo test with my BBB, however, when I use some command as (http://www.phys-x.org/rbots/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106:lesson-3-beaglebone-black-pwm&catid=46:beaglebone-black&Itemid=81) tutorial, I just find some serious problem with my pwm setting.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ianymu:/sys/devices/ocp.2/pwm_test_P8_13.14$ ls
modalias  power  subsystem  uevent
```

I consider there are missing some file with my BBB. it should includes `, , ,` .

So I try to use update it does not work, and use

```
sudo sh -c "echo am33xx_pwm > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots"

sudo sh -c "echo bone_pwm_P8_13 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots"
```

it all did not worked on it.

Guys, I have already asked many ask forum about this question, no one know how to fix that. somebody suggest me to change the DEBIAN or ANGSTROM.

I would like to figure it out what's going on with that problem.

Anyone can help me to solve that?

So, there are some information about my bbb and environment.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-ianymu:~$ uname -a Linux ubuntu-ianymu 3.8.13-bone20 #1 SMP Wed May 29 10:49:26 UTC 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

root@ubuntu-ianymu:/sys/kernel/debug# cat /sys/kernel/debug/pwm
platform/48304100.ecap, 1 PWM device
 pwm-0   ((null)              ):

platform/48304200.ehrpwm, 2 PWM devices
 pwm-0   ((null)              ):
 pwm-1   ((null)              ):

platform/48302200.ehrpwm, 2 PWM devices
 pwm-0   ((null)              ):
 pwm-1   ((null)              ):

platform/48300100.ecap, 1 PWM device
 pwm-0   ((null)              ):

platform/48300200.ehrpwm, 2 PWM devices
 pwm-0   ((null)              ):
 pwm-1   ((null)              ):
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your kernel does not have full PWM support - normally you would have

```
ls /sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_P8_13.13/                                                                  
driver  duty  modalias  period  polarity  power  run  subsystem  uevent
```

duty, period, polarity and so on are available only if you compiled the Kernel with the flag `CONFIG_EHRPWM_TEST` enabled.

For instance, [eelinux Ubuntu raring Kernel 3.8.13-bone48](https://rcn-ee.net/deb/raring-armhf/v3.8.13-bone48/defconfig) has the module enabled.

Comment: Thank your reply and I have already change the ubuntu to Debian from the BB latest website.